# Split string into array that is enclosed in capturing parentheses

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I have the following string in my project:

`((1,01/31/2015)(1,Filepath)(1,name)(1,code)(1,String)(1,    ))`

I want to split this string into parts where i get the information within the capturing parentheses (for example `1,Filepath` or `(1,Filepath)`, but the whole string is in capturing parentheses too as you can see. The result i then try to put into array with `string[] array = Regex.Split(originalString,SomeRegexHere)`

Now i am wondering what would be the best approach be, just remove the first and last character of the string so i don't have the capturing parentheses enclosing the whole string, or is there some way to use Regular expressions on this to get the result i want to ?

Comment: Since you know that the first and last characters are parentheses, I'd just remove them and match the rest of the data.  RegEx would work ok for that.

Comment: Not `RegEx.Split`, you'll need `RegEx.Match`

Comment: You shouldn't be concerned about performance at this point.  The difference is going to be in milliseconds.

Comment: Could `Filepath` or `String` contain parentheses? E.g. "C:\temp\file (1).txt" or "This is a string (with parentheses)."

Comment: yes, the filepath can be any real filepath, so in theory it could have parentheses in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string s = "((1,01/31/2015)(1,Filepath)(1,name)(1,code)(1,String)(1,    ))";
var data = s.Split(new string[]{"(", ")"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

your Data would be then

```
["1,01/31/2015",
 "1,Filepath", 
 "1,name", 
 "1,code", 
 "1,String", 
 "1,"]
```

Comment: mm trying to use this one, but im getting a bunch of errors on the `(["(", ")"],` part, not sure why it doesn't like this.

Comment: my apologies.. was too consumed by javascript. i have edited the answer

Comment: Thank you, works perfect! though i need to be carefull not to use any parentheses in the filenames, as that would mess it up haha

Comment: @Dante1986 If you have parens in the filename and they aren't 'nice', then I don't think it would be possible to split your string (e.g. the filename `file )(.txt` is a valid name).

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\))
```

Just do a match and get your contents instead of splitting.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/15

Comment: Shall it be (?<=\()[^()]*(?=\)) to exclude the second "("

Comment: Yet, your pattern matches it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a substring without the first 2 and last 2 brackets and then split this on the enclosing brackets

```
    var s = "((1,01/31/2015)(1,Filepath)(1,name)(1,code)(1,String)(1, ))";

    var result = s.Substring(2, s.Length - 4)
                  .Split(new string[]{")("}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach(var r in result)
        Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Output

```
1,01/31/2015
1,Filepath
1,name
1,code
1,String
1,
```

[Example](https://ideone.com/slvkL6)